# Silverlight - game collision objects

Tags: silverlight

I am developing simple catching application in Silverlight (in Blend 4). Do you know how to simply solve object collision of falling objects from the top to the bottom into the white rectangle? Image - http://img94.imageshack.us/img94/8200/svlk.jpg

Thanks

current code:

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{ 
    int skore=0;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        chytac.Visibility=Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    private void UserControl_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        String k=e.Key.ToString();
        klavesa.Content=k;
        if(e.Key.ToString().Equals("Left")){
            double x=Canvas.GetLeft(chytac);
            x=x-20;
            if(x>0){
                Canvas.SetLeft(chytac,x);
            }   

        }
        if(e.Key.ToString().Equals("Right")){
            double x=Canvas.GetLeft(chytac);
            x=x+20;
            if(x<650){
                Canvas.SetLeft(chytac,x);
            }   

        }
    }

    private void start_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        chytac.Visibility=Visibility.Visible;
        start.Visibility=Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    private void random_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        //pocitadlo++;
        //score.Content=pocitadlo.ToString();
        telefon novy = new telefon();
        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(novy);
        Canvas.SetTop(novy, 0);
        Canvas.SetLeft(novy, random.Next(0,650));
        Canvas.SetZIndex(novy, -50);

        bomba bomba=new bomba();
        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(bomba);
        Canvas.SetTop(bomba, 0);
        Canvas.SetLeft(bomba, random.Next(0,650));
        Canvas.SetZIndex(bomba, -50);
    }
}
```

Comment: What code do you currently have, if any?

Comment: I have added my code - telefon and bomba are objects generated after clicking button random, chytac is rectange for cathing objects on the bottom

Comment: I'd move the declaration and initialisation of `random` out of the click method. Otherwise you'll get non random results if the user clicks frequently.

Comment: In final implementation, there will be timer for releasing random generating objects. But for now, I have problem with implementing game collision falling objects with rectangle used for objects catching...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can represent your object as a rectangle (or set of rectangles) you can simply check if rectange(s) overlap with the white rectangle. Complex shapes might require more advanced algorithms. There are number of sprite libraries available such as [Silversprite](http://silversprite.codeplex.com/)